# how to run a new controller under frontend directory in yii 2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

So I created a TestController file inside the frontend/controllers directory and then created a view/test directory with an index.php file inside it. my code for the TestController is this

```
<?php

namespace app\frontend\controllers;


use yii\web\Controller;



class TestController extends Controller{


    public function actionTest(){
        return $this->render('index');
    }


}
```

my index file only contains an echo of hello world.

my question now is, how to run this in the browser ?
I tried in the url

```
http://localhost/myapp/frontend/test/
```

I got an error

Not Found

```
The requested URL /myapp/frontend/test/ was not found on this server.
```

I also tried this

```
http://localhost/myapp/frontend/test/index
```

still won't work. so how ?

Comment: your using url manager?

Comment: How you config your Virtal host?

Comment: try `http://localhost/myapp/frontend/test/test` because your controller and action names are same, you don't have `index` action.

Comment: solved it via web/index?=test/index

Answer (score 0):

You try just

The fist test controller and second one view

http://localhost/myapp/frontend/test/test

OR

http://localhost/myapp/frontend/test/test/index